# How to make trailing stop bar index update to the starting bar of a trade

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a trailing stop script that starts plotting the trailing stop at a given bar index or bar time (from an input) and sends alerts to Oanda to update stop losses.
This script is placed within a strategy script and works perfectly when I specify the bar index at the beginning of a trade.

The trailing loss script is below

```
//Declare trailing variables
var trailPrice = 0.0
t_trailPrice = trailType == 'Long' ? ta.lowest(low, structureLookback) - atr : ta.highest(high, structureLookback) + atr

// Get symbol and broker
var symbol_1 = syminfo.basecurrency + '/' + syminfo.currency
var avPrefix = 'e=' + broker + ' s=' + symbol_1 + ' '

plot(strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0), color=color.green)
//Check for trailing stop update
if (bar_index >= barIndex and barIndex != 0 or time >= barTime and barIndex == 0) and barstate.isconfirmed
    //Trail long stop
    if (t_trailPrice > trailPrice or trailPrice == 0.0) and trailType == 'Long'
        trailPrice := t_trailPrice
        // Tell autoview to update our stop loss
        clearOrder = avPrefix + 'c=order\n'
        slOrder = avPrefix + 'c=position b=long fsl=' + str.tostring(trailPrice)
        alert(message=clearOrder + slOrder, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    //Trail short stop
    if (t_trailPrice < trailPrice or trailPrice == 0.0) and trailType == 'Short'
        trailPrice := t_trailPrice
        // Tell autoview to update our stop loss
        clearOrder = avPrefix + 'c=order\n'
        slOrder = avPrefix + 'c=position b=short fsl=' + str.tostring(trailPrice)
        alert(message=clearOrder + slOrder, freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)

// If long stop hit, reset trail stop
if trailPrice != 0.0 and low <= trailPrice and trailType == 'Long'
    trailPrice := na
    trailPrice

// If short stop hit, reset trail stop
if trailPrice != 0.0 and high >= trailPrice and trailType == 'Short'
    trailPrice := na
    trailPrice

//Draw data to chart
plot(trailPrice, color=color.new(color.yellow, 0), title='Trailing Stop')

plot(bar_index, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), title='Current Bar Index')
```

My Issue is that when a trade opens I would like to overwrite the old barIndex value with the bar index of the first bar in the open trade.

I have tried the following

Inserted this code into the above script
`// Get bar index if strategy.position_size != 0 barIndex := strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0)`
with this added in the trailing loss plot just disappears from the chart

I have also tried overwriting barIndex and trailType within my code that detects and sends alerts for my valid shorts and longs. (Only the long alert is pasted below to save space)

```
if validLong
    trailType := "Long"
    t_entry := close
    barIndex := bar_index // have also tried barIndex := strategy.opentrades.entry_bar_index(0)
    if longStopPrice < trailPrice
        longStopPrice := trailPrice
    t_stop := longStopPrice
    t_target := longTargetPrice
    t_direction := 1
    tradePositionSize := getPositionSize(toWhole(longStopDistance) * 10)
    strategy.entry(id='Long', direction=strategy.long, when=validLong, comment='(SL=' + str.tostring(truncate(toWhole(longStopDistance), 2)) + ' pips)')
    trailType := "Long"
    // Fire alerts
    if not av_use and not pc_use
        alert(message='Bullish Hammer Detected!', freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    // Trigger PineConnector long alert
    if pc_use
        alertString = pc_entry_alert('buy', t_stop, t_target)
        alert(alertString, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
    // Trigger AutoView long alert
    if av_use
        alert(message='e=' + broker + ' b=long q=' + str.tostring(tradePositionSize) + ' s=' + pair + ' t=' + (av_limitOrder ? 'limit fp=' + str.tostring(close) : 'market') + ' fsl=' + str.tostring(t_stop) + ' ftp=' + str.tostring(t_target) + (av_gtdOrder != 0 and av_limitOrder ? gtdString : ''), freq=alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can achieve what was described above?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have somewhere in your code a place where 'barIndex' is modified.
It prevents you to definitively record a value when a strategy.entry occurs.
You should find where 'barIndex' is updated in your code and then update only is the 'strategy.position_size == 0', so that once a strategy.entry is on, your 'barIndex' won't update anymore and stay at your desired value.

```
if strategy.position_size == 0
    barIndex := .... update the value
```